# Why the "Permalink" option is not showing in the "Settings"?

Tags: permalinks

I've just started using Wordpress online and I see that there's no "permalink" option in the settings. If anything is turned off or if I can bring the "Permalink" option with any code, please suggest how and where do I do that.

Comment: Hi Labib! What options do you have in your Settings menu?

Comment: Are you referring to a wordpress.org install or a site on wordpress.com - as you cannot change permalinks on the latter.